# not able to integrate to master branch because of earlier revert

Tags: git, git-merge, svn-reintegrate

I had a topic branch, and i merged my changes to the master branch. Because of some bug, i had to roll back my changes. I did this roll back by manually changing the code back to how it was originally, before i touched it.

This was because we were nearing a release, and it was important to get the problem out of the way immediately.

Now, i fixed the bug, and am trying to merge my topic branch to the master branch again. Because of the same commit id's, i am facing problems. I get the following error message:

`[code] Merge.warning: Merge commit already exists between origin/topic and master`

Is there any way to solve this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: just revert your revert.

Answer (score 0):

You could have performed a `git revert` to rollback your changes, rather than doing it manually. The same way, you can do a `git revert` of your rollback now.